# Using open graph actions to invite a user to your app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to publish actions to invite users to my app. I defined an "invite" custom action where the related object is the predefined "Profile" object. I'm trying to use it in a way that I can post "User X invited User Y" actions. I've done custom actions before, so I know the drill.

I managed to make the API calls using my test users, and I'm getting a new published action ID from the API. However, I'm not seeing the action in either the sender or the receiver feeds or timelines.

Important notes:

- The users are test users (both) and the action is un-submitted, however, doing something similar (with different type of object) worked well in the same conditions.
- For the object URL, I'm using the Facebook graph URL (https://graph.facebook.com/xxxx). The API seems to eat that fine.

What am I doing wrong?

PS. If you can think of a better way of implementing an invite mechanism, other than the requests dialog, I'm open to suggestions. To be clear, I don't have a "publish_stream" permissions, but I do have "publish_actions".

On a side note: I'm not sure how (or if) the receiver (the action object) will be notified.

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with the test users.  Do the actions show up on the test user's timeline profile (instead of looking in the timeline ticker?)

Comment: The action does not show up anywhere, although it was created successfully. The test users worked fine with previous actions.

Answer (score 0):

```
make a Folder named as : Controls

Then add this: InviteControl.aspx
simply write :
<span id="invitespan" runat="server"></span>

InviteControl.ascx.cs : 

public partial class Controls_InviteControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Show border or not
    /// </summary>
    public bool ShowBorder { set { showBorder = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Display email section
    /// </summary>
    public bool EmailInvite { set { emailInvite = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of rows. Allowed values are from 3 to 10. Default value is 5.
    /// </summary>
    public int Rows { set { rows = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of columns. Allowed values are from 2,3 and 15. Default value is 5.
    /// </summary>
    public int Colums { set { colums = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set comma separated string of friend ID which you don't want to be in invite list
    /// </summary>
    public string ExcludeFriends { set { excludeFriends = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// IList of friend IDs which you don't want to be in invite list
    /// </summary>
    public IList<long> ExcludeFriendsList
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                int i = 0;
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (long id in value)
                {
                    i++;
                    s.Append(id.ToString());
                    if (i < value.Count)
                    {
                        s.Append(",");
                    }
                }
                excludeFriends = s.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// URL where application should be redirected, after an invitation is sent.
    /// Default is application Canvas URL taken from web.config file.
    /// </summary>
    public string ActionUrl { set { actionUrl = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// URL where user will be redirected after the invite request is accepted.
    /// If it's not set, ActionUrl is used.
    /// </summary>
    public string AcceptUrl { set { acceptUrl = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Main description which will apear on invite request
    /// </summary>
    public string Content { set { content = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Application name displayed on send button and invite request title.
    /// Default is name taken from web.config file
    /// </summary>
    public string AppName { set { appName = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Title of confirmation button inside invite request. Default value is 'Accept'
    /// </summary>
    public string ConfirmButtonTitle { set { confirmButtonTitle = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Main title of control
    /// </summary>
    public string MainTitle { set { mainTitle = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Refresh display of the control
    /// </summary>
    public void Refresh()
    {
        if (mainTitle == null) throw new Exception("Invite Friends Error:  Main Title is not set.");        
        if (content == null) throw new Exception("Invite Friends Error:  Content is not set.");

        if (confirmButtonTitle == null) throw new Exception("Invite Friends Error:  Confirm Button Title is not set.");
        if (actionUrl == null) actionUrl = Core.AppConfig.AppCanvasUrl;

        if (acceptUrl == null) acceptUrl = actionUrl;
        if (appName == null) appName = Core.AppConfig.AppName;

        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.Append("<fb:serverfbml ");
        html.Append("width='" + width + "'>");
        html.Append("<script type='text/fbml'>");
        html.Append("<div style='" + cssStyle + "' class='" + cssClass + "'>");
        html.Append("<fb:fbml>");
        html.Append("<fb:request-form method=\"POST\" action=\"");
        html.Append(actionUrl);
        html.Append("\" content=\"");
        html.Append(content);
        html.Append("<fb:req-choice url='");
        html.Append(acceptUrl);
        html.Append("' label='");
        html.Append(confirmButtonTitle);
        html.Append("' />\" type=\"");
        html.Append(appName);
        html.Append("\" invite=\"true\">");
        html.Append("<fb:multi-friend-selector target=\"_top\" condensed=\"false\" exclude_ids=\"");
        html.Append(excludeFriends);
        html.Append("\"  actiontext=\"");
        html.Append(mainTitle);
        html.Append("\" showborder=\"");
        html.Append(showBorder);
        html.Append("\" rows=\"");
        html.Append(rows);
        if (colums < 5) // fixing bug in FBML (if columns == 5 it renders as it as 4)
        {
            html.Append("\" cols=\"");
            html.Append(colums);
        }
        html.Append("\" email_invite=\"");
        html.Append(emailInvite);
        html.Append("\" />");
        html.Append("</fb:request-form> ");
        html.Append("</fb:fbml>");
        html.Append("</div>");
        html.Append("</script>");
        html.Append("</fb:serverfbml>");

        invitespan.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Page Load
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Refresh();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Private members
    /// </summary>
    private string excludeFriends = "";
    private string actionUrl = null;
    private string acceptUrl = null;
    private string content = null;
    private string confirmButtonTitle = "Accept";
    private string appName = null;
    private string mainTitle = null;
    private bool showBorder = true;
    private bool emailInvite = true;
    private int rows = 4;
    private int colums = 4;
    private string cssStyle = "";
    private string cssClass = "";
    private int width = 625;


    /// <summary>
    /// Obsolete members/methods
    /// </summary>
    [Obsolete("You shouldn't use this property anymore. Use AppName instead")]
    public string SendButtonTitle { set { appName = value; } }
}


Then add a page : InviteFriends.aspx

copy and paste this :

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="InviteFriends.aspx.cs" Inherits="InviteFriends"
    EnableViewState="false" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/InviteControl.ascx" TagName="Invite" TagPrefix="cc" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <%= Core.AppConfig.AppName %></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lInitFB" />
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div runat="server" id="dvCanvas">
                <div id="workfield">
                    <div id="invite">
                        <cc:Invite runat="server" ID="ccInvite" ActionUrl="http://cflluxury.allsocialassets.com/InviteFriends.aspx"
                            Content="Invite to Luxury app" ConfirmButtonTitle="Confirm" MainTitle="Luxury App" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>

    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

    <script>
        FB.init({
            appId: '414171951949853',
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true // parse XFBML
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Then give a link to that invite page from your default page: 

<a href="InviteFriends.aspx">Invite Friend</a>

Hope it will help.
```

Comment: Thanks. That would be the requests dialog which is geared towards canvas apps, not web sites. I'm not looking for that. Appreciate you taking the time and writing it, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't post an OG action to the user's friend's wall without them first authorizing your app as well as consenting to having those actions published beforehand. Furthermore, receiving an invite is not what actions are for. Nor does Facebook's policy allow you two tag users in an action unless they actually performed that action together (literally in the same location, or virtually in your app).